# ios "Slide to View" never launches app after push notification

Tags: ios, apple-push-notifications

Im working on an IOS app in 7.1 using APNS.  I get the push
notification successfully, however it never seems to launch my app
after I "Slide to View".  APNS works successfully when app is in "Active"
state, and even when the device is still lit but at the home screen (no
apps running except in background), it will launch and go to the screen i want.

From everything Ive read, this should enter at 'didFinishLaunchingWithOptions'

Ive tried running the app in XCode, then hitting the home button and waiting for
the screen to timeout and go blank, then pushing a notification to see if I could
breakpoint it but that didnt work either.

Suggestions? or better way to debug this?

Any help is appreciated.
Thank you!

Comment: I just tried the same thing in my app and it does launch into `didFinishLaunchingWithOptions` after I tap the APNS notification.

Are you sure you got your App Bundle ID correct in Xcode?

Comment: Does the app receive the pushes if the app is in the foreground?

Comment: Yes, I get push notifications to the device in all cases.  Push is definitely working.  The only case that is not working is when the device is not active, thats what makes this so curious.

Answer (score 0):

Turns out this is not a problem.  Text messages behaves this way already.
I had thought that it launches the app but it does not, it only opens to
the home screen.  Not an issue now.